# Representing multidimensional array when passing GET

Tags: php

Is there a way to represent/pass a multidimensional array like

```
array( array('foo' => 'bar') , array('language' => 'php'), ...);
```

into a GET string?

For simple arrays such as

```
array(1,2,3,4)
```

I can represent it like this

```
?ids=1,2,3,4
```

But I don't know how to represent multidimensional arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several ways you could do it.

One way is to [serialize()](http://php.net/serialize) it and then [unserialize()](http://php.net/unserialize) it on the page that reads it.

Another way is to [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) it and then [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) it on the page that reads it.

Or, in keeping with the CSV-style it sounded like you prefer, you could just delimit the next layer of the array with a different delimiter, ex.

```
array(
    0 => array(1, 2, 3),
    1 => array(4, 5, 6),
)
```

becomes

```
?array=1|2|3,4|5|6
```

Finally, PHP will also parse arrays in the querystring like:

```
?array[0][0]=1&array[0][1]=2&array[0][1]=3&array[1][0]=4&array[1][1]=5&array[1][1]=6
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the same square bracket notation as when submitting form post data, eg

```
?array[][foo]=bar&array[][language]=php

$array = $_GET['array'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any standard way to do this. You can roll your own by using a space character as a row delimiter:

```
array( array(1, 2, 3, 4), array(5, 6, 7) );
```

becomes

```
?ids=1,2,3,4+5,6,7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to prevent any disambiguation:

```
?ids=1|2|3|4||23|34|45
```

its easy to implement and read.

at the reciever's end, you just need to explode the GET parameter back to an array, eg:

```
$par=explode($_GET[ids],"||");
```

or

```
$par=explode($_GET[ids],"|");
```